# C# LINQ OrderBy() Expression, Creating Nested Generic type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I have a `class Person`

```
class Person
{
   string Name;
   int Age;
   DateTime BirthDate;
}
```

I am trying to create an `Expression` to order an `IQueryable<Person>` by a given property name.

```
public IQueryable<Person> Order(IQueryable<Person> input, string sortColumnName)
{
    Type type = typeof(Person);

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(sortColumnName);
    Type pType = prop.Type;

    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(type, "y");
    Expression prop = param;

    prop = Expression.Property(prop, propertyInfo);

    // I want to achieve..
    // var orderExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, "pType">>(prop, param);

    // In order to do something like the above statement, 
    // I have to create a nested generic type of `Func<Person, "pType">`
              
    Type e1 = typeof(Expression<>);

    Type[] typeArgs = {typeof( Func <Person, pType>)};
     
    Type orderType = e1.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

    // Need some help of how to create and use this Generic ""orderType"".

    // ....
    // Ultimately, it will by used somewhat like ...
    // 
    // var orderExpression = Expression.Lambda<"orderType">(prop, param);

    return input.OrderBy(orderExpression);
}
```

I am really confused by this inconsistent behavior of `Expression trees`.

In my project, I have an `""IQueryable<Person>"".Where(w1)` that can easily take in an `Expression w1`.

I am simply trying to do the same by creating an `""IQueryable<Person>"".OrderBy(o1)`,
to successfully consume an `Expression o1`.

I would prefer to keep everything as `IQueryable<>`, instead of having to convert back and forth to `IEnumerable<>`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'll left common solution. Expression tree is a nightmare only from start.

```cs
public IQueryable<T> Order(this IQueryable<T> input, string sortColumnName)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);

    var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(sortColumnName);
    if (propertyInfo == null)
       throw new InvalidOperationException();

    var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "y");
    var orderLambda = Expression.Lambda(
       Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, propertyInfo), 
       param);

    var queryExpr = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable), 
        "OrderBy", 
         new Type[] { 
                input.ElementType, 
                propertyInfo.PropertyType },
        input.Expression,
        orderLambda);
    
    return input.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(queryExpr);
}
```

Note, that I can make small mistake because just writing from memory.